# Where does Moodle store the files that users upload for their assignments?

Tags: storage, moodle

Imagine that a user uploads a file called "myAssignment.docx" to Moodle to complete the submission of an assignment. Where would the folder containing "myAssignment.docx" be? Is it in the moodledata folder outside the public web directory or somewhere else? I am trying to locate that folder because I want to monitor its growth to determine when I should upgrade my web hosting service to provide more storage space for files that students upload to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/File_API_internals#File_storage_on_disk

The simple answer is inside:

$CFG->dataroot.'/filedir'

Comment: Useful answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It is stored in /repository directory from Ver 3.62.

You may have subdirectories. Check which one is used for the purpose.

Comment: Moodle doesn't have a version 3.62. There is a version 3.6.2, but I can't see any mention of such a major change to the way that the internal file storage works ( https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_3.6.2_release_notes ) - could you include a link to the Moodle tracker ticket where this change was made?